# I'm executing my code and getting the error "Unable to locate the Javac Compiler"

Tags: java

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project wovv-target: Compilation failure
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Seems like you don't have `javac` installed. Have you tried installing it?

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maven trying to find javac in wrong directory, first check your JAVA_HOME system variable. I am recommended install maven on system and config NetBeans to use it instead bundled maven.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

after that check maven installation by mvn -v command

```
 mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T22:39:06+03:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

ps. i am using bash if you use cmd standard win console replace $ to % like

```
 echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

also make NetBeans use your system installed maven like this:

[image]